# xcode 15 not showing the destination of device ios 15

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native, ios-simulator

I can't see as destination of the simulator ios 15 device, and I don't understand why?
By the way I don't use ios 17 device because it makes bugging a react-native component (react-native-modal-datetime-picker).
Here in the image below, you see I installed and launched the iphone 13 pro ios 15 and it proposes only ios 17 in destinations in xcode.
[image]

Comment: It looks like you haven't installed the iOS development environment. Click on "Get" to install it. You have to use the iOS 17 SDK, even if your target device has iOS 15 installed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install ios sdk (for XCode 15 it will be 17th version) and then download the old one you need.

[image: iOS 17 and 16.4 installation window]
[image: Result of installation both of them]

Answer (score 1):

You have to press GET on your image there where it says "iOS 17.0 Not Installed" in order for iOS devices to show up.